# Change Value of another column based on characters of string from first column python, pandas, df.loc

Tags: python, string, pandas, parsing

I am attempting to change the value of a record based on the character in string from a different column. So if the second to last character of one string is a number (0-9) and the last character of is a letter (a-z) then change the value of a different column.

I cant post code that i have due to formatting.

```
alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
alpha = [x.upper() for x in alpha]
numbers  = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
df.loc[(df['CI Name'][-1].isin(alpha, na=False)) & (df['Device Category'] == 'Servers') & (df['CI Name'][-2].isin(numbers, na=False)), 'Device Category'] = 'Server Alias'
```

I would like the Device Category to be changed based on these conditions:

```
1) if second to last character in CI name is a number
2) and last character in CI Name is a letter
3) and the Device Category is currently labeled 'Servers'
```

I cant paste the error code due to formatting issues

I have tried a few things but i cannot post them due to formatting issues

I want device category to change based on character in code.

Comment: alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
alpha = [x.upper() for x in alpha]
numbers  = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']

df.loc[(df['CI Name'][-1].isin(alpha, na=False)) & (df['Device Category'] == 'Servers') & (df['CI Name'][-2].isin(numbers, na=False)), 'Device Category'] = 'Server Alias'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[(df['CI Name'].str[-1].isin(alpha, na=False)) 
       & (df['Device Category'] == 'Servers') 
       & (df['CI Name'].str[-2].isin(numbers, na=False)), 'Device Category'] = 'Server Alias'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use str function and regex to match digit and alphabet like below

```py
# find boolean index matching condition
bool_index = df["CI Name"][~df["CI Name"].isnull()].str[-2:] \
    .str.match("^\d[a-zA-Z]") & (df["Device Category"] == 'Server')

# set value to col1 for matching rows
df.loc[bool_index, "col1"] = "alias"
```